# Google Oauth2 Server side flow java with Refresh token

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-oauth-java-client

I am trying to fetch some data from GoogleAnalytics through a java application running inside a VM.

I have a refresh token ready with me available and I want to use this refresh token to generate an auth token and eventually get data from GA.

This is how my current code looks like.

```
private static String getAccessToken(String refreshToken) throws IOException {
        TokenResponse tokenResponse = new GoogleRefreshTokenRequest(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, refreshToken, googleClientId, googleClientSecret)
                .setScopes(AnalyticsScopes.all())
                .setGrantType("refresh_token")
                .execute();
        return tokenResponse.getAccessToken();
    }

public Credential getCredentials() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = GoogleAnalyticsDataImportService.class.getResourceAsStream(CLIENT_SECRET_JSON_RESOURCE);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CLIENT_SECRET_JSON_RESOURCE);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        String clientId = clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId();
        String clientSecret = clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret();

        Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret)
                .build();

        String refreshToken = "<REFRESH-TOKEN>"; //Find a secure way to store and load refresh token
        credential.setAccessToken(getAccessToken(refreshToken));
        credential.setRefreshToken(refreshToken);

        return credential;
    }
```

The issue here is that `GoogleCredentials` is deprecated and I can't find a way to create the Credentials class without it to use refreshToken.

I also tried another flow, but this opens up the browser to get the user authenticated, but I don't want that.
The frontend will handle the user authentication and I plan to store the refresh token in a database securely for future API access.

How can I use the refresh token and create a credentials class so that I can access Google Analytics Data?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the GoogleCredential class Java Doc you could look

https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java

I quick looked it. should be ok to get token by GoogleCredentials instead of the deprecated GoogleCredential

```
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new 
FileInputStream("/path/to/credentials.json"));
credentials.refreshIfExpired();
AccessToken token = credentials.getAccessToken();
// OR
AccessToken token = credentials.refreshAccessToken();
```